# Cómo hacer que una función Draw se repita a si misma cuando hago click con el mouse?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una funcion `MouseClicked` dentro de una `Draw Function`, la finalidad es que cada vez que el usuario haga "`click`", aparezca un elemento. Pero quiero que el elemento se siga repitiendo, sin la necesidad de volver a hacer "`click`"

Gracias :)

```
noStroke(); <br>
var xPositions = [random(10, 390)];<br>
var yPositions = [random(71, 80)];<br>
var colors = [];<br>


  var dibujoBackground = function () { //>>>> conjunto de varias figuras, estoy seguro que pueden ignorar está función

    //sól
        fill(255, 247, 0);
        ellipse(-2, 83, 70, 78);
        noFill();
        stroke(255, 247, 0);
        arc(0, 85, 70, 78, -28, 91);
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 191, 0);
    rect(0, 0, 470, 71); 

// floor, outside window

    fill(235, 235, 235); 
    noStroke();
    rect(-23, 354, 430, 74); // floor
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    rect(-3, 389, 500, 10); // street?

// buildings
    noStroke();
    fill(130, 130, 130);
    rect(288, 156, 100, 215);

    fill(166, 166, 166);
    rect(183, 196, 86, 181);

    fill(209, 209, 209);
    rect(-33, 175, 100, 200);


// trees


for (var x1 = 79; x1 < 467; x1 += 72) {
    var y1 = 353;
    stroke(140, 89, 122);
    strokeWeight(3);
    line(x1, 384, x1, y1);

    //leaves
        var leaf = [28, 23, 18]; // sizes of the tree

        strokeWeight(0.5);
        stroke(0, 179, 33);
        fill(0, 255, 47);

        ellipse(x1, 353, leaf[0], leaf[0]);
        ellipse(x1, 339, leaf[1], leaf[1]);
        ellipse(x1, 327, leaf[2], leaf[2]);


}


// marcos de la ventana

    stroke(255, 191, 0); 
    strokeWeight(1.5);
    line(0, 270, 400, 270);
    line(260, 71, 260, 400);};
```

draw = function() {
// ------>> Mi duda está dentro de está función

```
background(202, 233, 235);
dibujoBackground(); 

 //lluvia:
  for (var i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++) {

        noStroke();
        // colores al azar de la lluvia
        var color = { 
            r: random(0, 250),
            g: random(0, 250),
            b: random(0, 250)
        };
        colors.push(color);
        fill(colors[i].r, colors[i].g, colors[i].b); // color
        ellipse(xPositions[i], yPositions[i], 10, 10); // forma de la lluvia
        yPositions[i] += 5; // velocidad con que cae la lluvia
    }

 // clicks --->>> aquí está mi duda

    mouseClicked  = function () { // necesito que cada vez que se usa "clickea" la ellipse (la lluvia) siga siendo llamada sin necesidad de volver a hacer "click"

        if ( mouseY < 50) {         

            xPositions.push(mouseX);
            yPositions.push(mouseY + 100);
        } if (mouseY < 71) { 

            xPositions.push(mouseX);
            yPositions.push(mouseY + 50);
        } else{

            xPositions.push(mouseX);
            yPositions.push(mouseY);
        }
    };};
```

Comment: bueno, primero debes poner algo de codigo para poder entender mejor, ya que las ideas en el aire son dificil de formarlas. JJ

Comment: Disculpa, se me pasó. Ya edito la pregunta y lo agrego. Gracias :)

Comment: y en que momento debe dejar de pintar ???

Comment: Que se repita algunas veces sería lo ideal, principalmente quiero saber cómo decirle al programa que repita algo de este estilo

Comment: bro, si ya tiene la funcion que dibuja y ya sabes cuando llamarlo, entonces ahora solo es cuestion de que metas esa funcion dentro de una esctructura ciclica y listo Bro...

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas que la funcion se repita constantemente cada cierto intervalo hasta cierto punto o hasta siempre utiliza `setInterval()`:

 Te permite indicar una funcion y un intervalo de tiempo en milisegundos indicando cada cuanto tiempo relanzarla
Ejemplo:

```
var repeticionLluvia = setInterval(lluvia, 1000); 
// En los parámetros el `1 `es la función a repetir y el `2` el intervalo de tiempo
```

Una vez ejecutado esta función se ejecutara de forma infinita cada 1000 mili segundos.
Si necesitas detenerlo en algún momento, cuando se cumpla alguna condición o algo, utiliza `clearInterval()`:

```
clearInterval(repeticionLluvia);
```

Como paramento le pasas la variable `repeticiónLluvia` la cual indica/contiene el la función de repetición.

Documentacion Oficial:

> [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)
>   [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) *No esta traducido, por lo tanto solo esta en ingles*